# Pasar datos del formulario a la tabla

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="row">
     <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" class="col s12">
      <div class="input-field col s1">
      <label>Folio</label>
      <input type="number" name="folio" id="folio"/>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <label for="first_name" >Nombre/Destino</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="validate">
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col s4">
        <input type="text" name="entrega" id="nombre" class="datepicker">
        <label for="first_name">Entrega de prestamo</label>
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col s3">
        <input type="text" name="devolucion" id="devolucion" class="datepicker">
        <label for="first_name">Devolución del prestamo</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div name="concepto" class="row">
    <label name="concepto" >Seleciona un concepto</label>
     <select name="concepto" class="input-field col s12">
      <option name="concepto" value="" disabled selected>Elije tu opción</option>
      <option name="concepto" value="1">Equipo de computo</option>
      <option name="concepto" value="2">Material diverso u otro</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s6">
    <label for="first_name" >Cantidad</label>
     <input name="cantidad" id="cantidad" type="number"> 
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col s6">
     <label for="Des">Descripción del equipo</label>
     <input name="descripcion" id="descripcion" type="text"> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s6">
   <label>Quien solicita</label>
   <input name="solicita" id="solicita" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s6">
   <label>Quien autoriza</label>
   <input name="autoriza" id="autoriza" type="text">
   </div>     
   </div>

   <div class="row">
  <a href="iniciodelapag.html"><input type="button" value="Regresar" style="background-color:#607d8b;"></a>
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" value="Submit form" id="guardar"  style="background-color:#607d8b;">
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hola Julissa, necesitas aprender como hacer una buena pregunta.  No solo pongas el codigo, explica bien que es lo que quieres lograr.  Hablas de una tabla pero no veo ninguna en tu codigo.

Comment: Como dice @alanfcm, falta información para lograr entender cuál es tu problema. Y dado que veo que usas `PHP_SELF`, me permito advertirte que esta práctica puede ser peligrosa si no se tomas precauciones, [he expuesto aquí la causa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239658/29967), mostrando un escenario de posible ataque XSS.