# Insertar en el array y que se muestre en una tabla el contenido añadido

Tags: php, html

mi problema viene desde que en clase nos mandaron realizar un ejercicio en el que se incluye un formulario y una variable de tipo array asociativa.
El ejercicio en sí consiste en construir un pequeño diccionario español/inglés, en el que inicializo un array asociativo con estas 5 palabras ya traducidas y éstas se muestran en una tabla generada dinámicamente mediante un `foreach`.

Hasta entonces todo bien, pero el problema surge, no cuando agrego elementos en el array, sino cuando quiero que se muestren en la tabla. Es por ello que había pensado en un `<input type="hidden">` y la serialización de estos elementos en el atributo `value` del `hidden`.
Sé que lo ideal es emplear una variable de sesión (`$_SESSION`), pero **no nos permiten utilizarla** porque lo veremos en unidades posteriores.

Coloco mi código HTML (archivo 'index.php'):

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Mi diccionario</title>
        <?php

$diccionario = array(
    "hecho" => "done",
    "correr" => "run",
    "estudiar" => "study",
    "estupido" => "stupid",
    "agua" => "water"
);

        if (isset($_POST["oculto"])) 
        {
               $diccionario = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["oculto"]));
        }
        else
        {
               $diccionario;
        }

        ?>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="contenedor">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Traducciones</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Español</th>
                    <th>Inglés</th>
                </tr>

<?php

            muestraPalabrasEnTabla($diccionario);

?>

            </table>
            <div id="formulario">
                <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                    <br/>
                    <fieldset>

                        <legend>Diccionario</legend>
                        <br/>

                        <div id="texts">

                            Español:<input type="text" name="espanol" placeholder="Palabra en español"><br/>
                            Inglés:<input type="text" name="ingles" placeholder="Palabra en inglés"><br/>
                        </div>

                        <div id="submits">
                            <br/>
                            <input type="submit" name="anadir" value="Añadir">
                            <input type="submit" name="eliminar" value="Eliminar">
                            <input type="submit" name="comprobar" value="Comprobar">
                            <input type="submit" name="prefijo" value="Prefijo">
                            <input type="submit" name="aIngles" value="A inglés">
                            <input type="submit" name="aEspanol" value="A español">
                            <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($diccionario));?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div id="resultados">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['anadir'])) 
{
    anadirDiccionario($diccionario);
}
```

Y la función de añadir al diccionario es la siguiente:

```
function anadirDiccionario($miArray) {
    $espanol = $_POST['espanol'];
    $ingles = $_POST['ingles'];

    if (!empty($espanol) && !empty($ingles)) {
        if (!key_exists($espanol, $miArray)) {
            $miArray[$espanol] = $ingles;
            //print_r($miArray);
//            echo "<br>";
            echo "Añadido al diccionario";
        } else {
            echo "Ya existe esta traducción";
            //print_r($miArray);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Introduzca la traducción que quiere añadir";
        //print_r($miArray);
    }
}
```

Así que mi duda en realidad es, ¿Por qué no me está insertando en la tabla el contenido si se lo estoy pasando medianto un oculto los datos y se sigue mostrando lo mismo siempre? 
No me está mostrando ningún error de código y en el `print_r` que tengo comentado se ve que inserta correctamente en el array.

Agregaré también el código de la función que muestra todo en la tabla:

```
function muestraPalabrasEnTabla($miArray) {
    foreach ($miArray as $key => $value) 
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$key</td>";
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Uno de los problemas es el orden, si primero muestras la tabla y después añades otro elemento no se va a mostrar por que ya se ejecutó. Por otro lado estás añadiendo la traducción dentro de la función pero dicha función no retorna nada y esa modificación se realiza solo en el ámbito local de esa función. Tampoco queda muy claro que es lo que tratas de hacer. Trata de explicarte mejor, indicando los valores que tienes que se ha de realizar y como debe quedar por ejemplo.

Comment: Otra cosa que no se entiende es por qué declaras `$diccionario` al principio como un array con ciertos valores y luego aquí: `if (isset($_POST["oculto"]))` lo redefines de nuevo  ¿?  Cabe decir que en caulquier caso el `else` de ese `if` sobra. También, si te están enseñando a usar `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` puede que estés aprendiendo en base a malas prácticas de programación ( [ver aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239658/29967) ).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu aportación, soy novato en todo esto e incluso desconocía qué es un ataque XSS. Sin duda que me será de ayuda para el futuro, ya que lo tendré en cuenta! 
Mil gracias!!

Comment: Puede ser que el texto que he escrito haya sido un poco largo y dé lugar a confusión. Lo que busco es: dado un array con cinco elementos ($diccionario), mediante el formulario se le añada una palabra en español y su traducción en inglés. El problema es que al accionar el botón "añadir" ($_POST["anadir"]) añada en el array la clave (en español) y el valor (en inglés) y que se muestre en la tabla. Todo ello sin usar variables de sesión ($_SESSION) y en un mismo fichero. Probé también el orden de colocar la tabla debajo de donde llamo a la función anadirDiccionario($diccionario) pero no funcionó.