# Error Notice: Undefined index: accion in URL on line 57

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema cuando invoco la primera pagina me da undefined index en los dos GET accion==servicio y accion==complemento, ya cuando entro en las otras dos acciones esta perfecto.

```
$pag=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  // el nombre y ruta de esta misma página.
if (!isset($_GET['accion'])){
echo <<< HTML
Codigo html
HTML;
}
if ($_GET['accion']=="servicio"){
echo <<< HTML

Codigo html
HTML;
}
```

Comment: aparentemente es cosa del if. compruebas un !isset, y luego de cerrar ese if, abres otro comprobando una variable que todavia puede estar a null. quizas podrias cambiar el segundo if por "elseif", de esta manera te aseguras que $_GET['accion'] esta definido

Comment: Gracias me sirvió, creía que con una cadena de if podría ejecutar la orden.

Comment: No deberías usar `PHP_SELF` si tienes otras alternativas. Y si la usas, deberías **filtrarla**, como debes hacer cuando usas cualquier otra variable de `$_SERVER`, al ser variables por las que te pueden colar ataques XSS u otros. [Ver más detalles aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239658/29967).