# Duda con uso de $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] en función PHP para Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, funciones

Buscando en la web encontré una función que necesitaba para mi proyecto pero me gustaría que alguien me explicara parte de ella. La función lo que hace es redirigir los usuarios a una página determinada si no han iniciado sesión y funciona correctamente.

En concreto es ésta.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('add page slug or ID here') && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
    exit;
   }
}
```

Y entiendo todo lo que hace perfectamente pero con éste trozo es que tengo dudas, no se lo que hace.

```
&& $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' )
```

La razón de crear ésta pregunta es que necesito saber o entender el código que estoy introduciendo a mi proyecto, primero para ganar en conocimientos y segundo para evitar posibles problemas o conflictos y que luego no sepa identificarlos.
Gracias a quien pueda ayudar

Comment: Y ya investigas te algo al respecto?, Te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: Creo, según lo que he investigado, que la condición significa  (si no es una petición ajax) pero no estoy seguro. Por eso pregunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta ejecutando la función PHP_SELF, puedes leer [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) mas del tema o bien [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239648/enviar-formulario-a-la-misma-p%C3%A1gina-con-url-o-php-self) que da un buen ejemplo del uso de PHP_SELF y sus riesgos

Técnicamente lo que haces es verificar que el usuario no este logueado, que sea la pagina especificada y por ultimo que no estés en el fichero mencionado "admin-ajax.php" en la función, por lo que no debería de haber problema con el uso de esa función.

Otra forma con la que podrías probar es con JavaScript, de esta forma

```
function redirectPage() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location.href='tu-url/';
      </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'redirectPage');
```

Esto hace lo mismo pero con JavaScript, técnicamente agrega un script que redirecciona a la URL proporcionada si el usuario no esta logueado

Comment: Excelente, gracias por su respuesta. Duda aclarada.