# Subir datos de un form a base de datos phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo un trabajo y tengo que subir un form a una base de datos mysqli, ví un par de vídeos pero ninguno me llegó a resolver mis dudas, y el caso es que el form consta de varios inputs, unos 3 campos de textos, un checkbox y un radio como veréis abajo, tengo un archivo que se llama con_db.php en el cual esta la información de la base de datos. Creo que el problema está en como he asignado las variables, pero por mucho que cambio el código no lo consigo arreglar. Cuando lo ejecuto, todo parece ir bien sólo que en la base de datos no aparece nada, es raro ya que el archivo dónde se encuentran los datos de la base de datos no lo he tocado. Bueno, os dejo el código y la foto:

[image: estructura de la base de datos]

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
} 

include("con_db.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

        $dueno = trim($_SESSION["username"]);
        $precio = trim($_POST["precio"]);
        $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
        $descripcion = trim($_POST['descripcion']);

        $Tecnologia = trim($_POST['Tecnologia']);
        $Ocio = trim($_POST['Ocio']);
        $Comida = trim($_POST['Comida']);
        $Miscelaneo = trim($_POST['Miscelaneo']);
        $Ciencia = trim($_POST['Ciencia']);
        $Herramienta = trim($_POST['Herramienta']);
        $Vehiculo = trim($_POST['Vehiculo']);

         if(isset($_POST['adispo'])){
            $status = $_POST["1"];
        }if(isset($_POST['bdispo'])){
            $status = $_POST["2"];
        }if(isset($_POST['cdispo'])){
            $status = $_POST["3"];
        }
        $link = "image";

        $consulta = "INSERT INTO productos(dueno, precio, status, descripcion, nombre, tags, links) VALUES ('$dueno','$precio','$status','$descripcion','$nombre','$Ocio','$link')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
    
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos2.css?v=1"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <title>Creat - Vender</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>¡Nos alegramos de que quieras hacer más grande esta web, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>!</h1>
        <h2>¡Rellena este pequeño formulario para subir un producto!</h2>
    </header>
</body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <form class="w3-container" method="post">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <div class="contenedor-precio">
                    <label class="etiqueta-precio" for="lname">Precio: </label>
                    <input name="precio" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text"></input><br>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-nombre">
                    <label class="etiqueta-nombre" for="lname">Nombre: </label>
                    <input name="nombre" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text"></input><br>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-descripcion">
                    <label class="etiqueta-descripcion" for="lname">Descripción: </label>
                    <input name="descripcion" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text"></input><br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="contenedor-etiquetas">
                    <label class="etiqueta-etiquetas" for="lname">Etiquetas: </label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Tecnologia">
                        <label for="Tecnologia"> Tecnología</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Ocio">
                        <label for="Ocio"> Ocio</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Comida">
                        <label for="Comida"> Comida</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Miscelaneo">
                        <label for="Miscelaneo"> Misceláneo</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Ciencia">
                        <label for="Ciencia"> Ciencia</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Herramienta">
                        <label for="Herramienta"> Herramienta</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="checkbox" name="Vehiculo">
                        <label for="Vehiculo"> Vehículo</label> <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="contenedor-disponibilidad">
                    <label class="etiqueta-disponibilidad" for="lname">Disponibilidad: </label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="radio" name="adispo">
                        <label for="1">Hay disponibilidad</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="radio" name="bdispo">
                        <label for="2">Hay disponibilidad según la demanda</label>
                        <input class="w3-input" type="radio" name="cdispo">
                        <label for="3">No hay disponibilidad</label> <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-teal" style="width:100%" type="submit" name="register"></input>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Te falta el atributo `action` en el `form` para indicar a donde se supone que viajrán los datos (*al momento es lo que puedo notar en tu código a primera vista*)

Comment: Y que debería poner, ya que el php se encuentra en el mismo documento, disculpa mi ignorancia.

Comment: Lee aqui @alon https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239648/enviar-formulario-a-la-misma-p%C3%A1gina-con-url-o-php-self

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, ya lo pude arreglar.