# Error PDO Select en Login con PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, login

Estoy tratando de hacer un login en HTML y PHP, pero me está dando el error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on
> null

Este es mi fichero:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login de usuario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" class="login">
            <div><label>Usuario</label><input name="usuario" type="text" style="color:red"></div>
            <div><label>Contraseña</label><input name="clave" type="password"></div>
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="ENTRAR"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

   try
    {
            
        $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname= mi_dB",'mi_Usu','mi_Pass');
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        
        $bdd->exec("set names utf8");
                echo "Conexión realizada Satisfactoriamente";
    }
    
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo "La conexión ha fallado: " . $e->getMessage();
      echo "<script>alert('Error: conexión');</script>";
    }
     
     
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){

   
    $u = $_POST['usuario'];
    $c = MD5($_POST['clave']); // La función MD5() estará encriptando lo ingresado para comparar con lo guardado

    if($u == "" || $_POST['clave'] == null){ // Validamos que ningún campo quede vacío
        echo "<script>alert('Error: usuario y/o clave vacios!!');</script>"; // Se utiliza Javascript dentro de PHP
    }
    
    else
    {
       
        $stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =:usuario AND password =:contra");
    $stmt->execute(['usuario' => $u,'contra'=>$c]);
        // Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // Ejecutamos
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt -> rowCount() > 0)
        {
            header('location:listado.php'); // Si está todo correcto redirigimos a otra página
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Error: usuario y/o clave incorrectos');</script>";
        }

        $stmt->closeCursor(); // opcional en MySQL, dependiendo del controlador de base de datos puede ser obligatorio
        $stmt = null; // obligado para cerrar la conexi√≥n
        $bdd = null;

    }
}
 
?>
```

El error es en esta línea: `$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password =:contraseña");`

No sé si ayudará, pero no se por qué me genera un archivo llamado inicio sin extensión (no es inicio.php)con el mismo código fuente.

error del servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un typo y el problema está en `dbname= mi_dB`. PDO considera el espacio como parte del nombre de la base. Quítalo y que quede `dbname=mi_dB`.

Comment: Porque cierras dos veces el parentesis si solo estás utilizando uno? **$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password =:contraseña)");** Además, sugiero no usar la **Ñ** para nombrar variables o campos de la base de datos

Comment: @EvilFearzZ cambié contraseña por contra para evitar la Ñ y corregí los paréntesis. sigue dando el mismo fallo

Comment: @aeportugal ya cambie el espacio que me dijiste gracias, sigue fallando

Comment: el codigo que has proporcionado no va acuerde con el error que reportas, por ejemplo el: error al llamar a `query()` y en el codigo no hay ningun metodo o funcion llamado `query()`  ....

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 es lo que no entiendo, pero el error esta copiado del log del servidor

Comment: no que va hace falta informacion para poder ayudarte ... el error puede estar en cualquier otro archivo ... no necesariamente en ese...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 no hay mas archivos, esta todo en este php

Comment: puedes tomar una captura del archivo de log del servidor en donde sale el error? como lo indicaste....

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 añadida captura

Comment: ok ahora edita tu publicacion y agrega debajo de la imagen cual es la linea #52 del index.php que cita el error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemas. Trataré de enumerarlos aquí:

1. El uso de `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` no es seguro en tu escenario, considera poner la URL del archivo que maneja el `action` del formulario. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239658/29967) para más detalles.
2. No se entiende por qué estableces en PDO modos de error contradictorios  ¿?
3. El código está mal organizado. Para que no te pierdas demasiado, ve incorporando cada cosa una vez haya verificado que esa cosa es correcta o no es nula o vacía. Por poner un ejemplo, si estás pasando datos por POST, verifica primero que esos datos están y cuando estén, intenta la conexión que trabajará con esos datos.
4. En el caso concreto de PDO, que dispone de manejo de Excepciones, debes poner dentro del `try` todo aquello que pueda fallar, para capturar las Excepciones. Tú tienes el `prepare()` fuera del bloque `try ... catch`, lo cual no es coherente.
5. Como ya te señalaron en comentarios, evita el uso de `ñ`, acentos a carácteres especiales tanto en variables, como en elementos HTML o en nombres de tablas / columnas. Si no cuidas la codificación, esos nombres de variable pueden romper el código.
6. No debes usar `rowCount()` para consultas del tipo `SELECT`. El Manual de PHP es muy claro al respecto. Te aconsejo que leas la documentación de todas aquellas clases /  métodos que vayas a usar. No es para nada tiempo perdido.

Voy a intentar aplicar todo lo dicho en una propuesta de código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login de usuario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="PON-AQUI-LA-URL-DEL-ARCHIVO" method="post" class="login">
            <div><label>Usuario</label><input name="usuario" type="text" style="color:red"></div>
            <div><label>Contraseña</label><input name="clave" type="password"></div>
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="ENTRAR"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php    
    $u = $_POST['usuario'] ?? NULL;
    $c = $_POST['clave'] ?? NULL;    
    if( isset($_POST['login']) && $u && $c){
        $c = MD5($c); // La función MD5() estará encriptando lo ingresado para comparar con lo guardado
        try
        {            
            $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mi_dB",'mi_Usu','mi_Pass');
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);      
            $bdd->exec("set names utf8");
            echo "Conexión realizada Satisfactoriamente";
            $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =:usuario AND password =:contra";
            $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([':usuario' => $u,':contra'=>$c]);
        // Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // Ejecutamos
            $stmt->execute();
            $data=$stmt->fetch();
            $stmt=null;
            $bdd=null;
            if($data)
            {
                header('location:listado.php'); // Si está todo correcto redirigimos a otra página
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Error: usuario y/o clave incorrectos');</script>";
            }
        }    
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "La conexión ha fallado: " . $e->getMessage();
            echo "<script>alert('Error: conexión');</script>";
        }
    }    
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Error: usuario y/o clave vacios!!');</script>"; // Se utiliza Javascript dentro de PHP
    }                
?>
```

Hay más problemas, pero quedan fuera del alcance de esta respuesta. A saber:

- El Manual es claro con respecto a `MD5()`, las claves que se manejan con ese criterio no son seguras. Convendrías usar la combinación de `password_hash()` / `password_verify()`.
- El estilo de programación combinando PHP dentro de Javascript y además redirecciones, es algo del siglo pasado. Hoy día puedes usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para comunicar entre cliente y servidor de una forma elegante, moderna, cómoda, pudiendo pasar datos sin redirecciones innecesarias y se tener que recargar la página.

Comment: aunque tu respuesta resuelve el sin fin de errores en el codigo proporcionado ... no resuelve el problema/error principal relacionado al metodo `query()`

Answer (score 0):

Dejo un enlace a un [repositorio GitHub](https://github.com/parzibyte/simple-login-php) que lo hace en PHP (aunque sea del pasado) y además utiliza las sesiones.

En caso de que no sea correcto poner esto como respuesta, ruego me avisen y la elimino. La pongo porque a mí me sirvió para hacer el login mediante PHP y HTML.